# How to resolve this?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, simulation

I've the following problem to model and program it:

- suppose that we have a central server that provides 3 different services($S_1,S_2,S_3$), there are $N$ machines connected to this server: each machine sends requests to the server at different rates (suppose that the arrival rate for each service is a Poisson);
- suppose that for each machine, the request rate for $S_1$ is: $\lambda_1$;  the request rate for $S_2$ is: $\lambda_2$;   the request rate for $S_3$ is: $\lambda_3$.

my question is: how is the global arrival request rate for this server calculated? is it equal to $(\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3)/3$ ????

Thanks for all responses.

Answer (score 0):

Are the three servers independent? If they are, then the total arrival rate is $\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3$ if I recall my queuing theory correctly. If the arrival rates are not independent, then I am not sure...

Comment: non, there is just one server that offer three different services